# como puede hacer 3 consultas en una sola sentencia en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero hacer : Seleccione el máximo, mínimo y el promedio de las poblaciones de las ciudades.
se que

mínimo es así

```
SELECT MIN(column_name) 
FROM table_name WHERE condition;*
```

y *máximo asi

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE condition;*
```

pero nose como unirlas en una sola consulta y tampoco como sacar el promedio de las poblaciones de las ciudades.

esta es la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el máximo, mínimo y promedio como nuevas columnas o renglones?

Comment: nuevas columnas

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que poner la fórmula del agregado en la misma sentencia

```
SELECT MIN(column_name) as Minimo, MAX(column_name) as Maximo, AVG(column_name) as Media
FROM table_name 
WHERE condition;
```

Si lo quieres por código de país, por ejemplo, solo deberías realizar la agrupación, siguiendo la misma estrategia

```
SELECT CountryCode, MIN(column_name) as Minimo, MAX(column_name) as Maximo, AVG(column_name) as Media
FROM table_name 
WHERE condition
GROUP BY CountryCode;
```